# About can't export the performance problems

Tags: database, sql, vmware-vcenter

At first,let me describe my environment

My VirtualCenter is install on window 2008 ,and theDataBase that VC used is SQL 2008

I really want to ask is .....

When I use vsphere clinet to connect VC.....I got a problem.

the performance chart only can show "realtime "......

whatever I only want to view the chart , or I want to export the performance log .

when i manually want to export performance, and I select the time to 1 hour ,1 day ,1 month, or from a to b.

it showed "No performance data to report for selected objects"

only select realtime can export data normally.

Before I install Vsphere 4 , I install the SQL 2008 , used the schema in the install CD(I follow the step to create SQL DB for vSphere)

Could anybody help me how to solve this problem?

And if need any information ,just tell me to provide.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In VCenter, go to Administration, vCenter Server Settings, choose statistics and change the statistics level